# angular material mat-select looks empty in firefox

Tags: angular, angular-material

in one type of components in my project I have a mat-select. As you see in the picture below in the chrome it works perfectly fine.

before click:

[image]

after click:

[image]
(chrome)

But when I try to open the same page in Mozilla Firefox i get something like this instead. As you see it looks empty but logically it works fine.

before click:

[image]

after click:

[image]
(firefox)

the code is simple. It has a two-way binding with a var. Does any body have any idea why this happens?

```
  <div *ngIf="onEdit && key == 'relationship'" class="d-table-cell" style="float: left !important; max-width: 50%;">
      <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 2px">
          <mat-select placeholder="new relationShip" [(ngModel)]="editedValue">
              <mat-option [value]="'causes'">causes</mat-option>
              <mat-option [value]="'caused_by'">caused_by</mat-option>
              <mat-option [value]="'member_of'">member_of</mat-option>
              <mat-option [value]="'includes'">includes</mat-option>
              <mat-option [value]="'associated_with'">associated_with</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
      </div>
    </div>


  <div *ngIf="onEdit" style="float: right !important; width: 50%;margin-top: 10px;"  >
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="onSubmitEdit()" style="width: 10px; margin-right: 4%">submit</button>
    <button mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="onEdit = !onEdit">cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems chrome has some kind of defaults for angular materials. It's not necessary to put some CSS styles for example for it's width, but in it's necessary for firefox.
All I did was adding width to it's style property and it looked perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you report this as an error to Angular Material?

Comment: @Henry. Nope. I didn't